# Como exportar/crear un archivo Excel(tabla) a Json, mediante codigo con nodejs y javascript usando el SheetsJS package?

Tags: javascript, json, nodejs, excel, simplexlsx

```
var XLSX = require("xlsx");


function converterExcelToJson()
{
    // Read the WorkBook
    let f_excelWB = XLSX.readFile(
        "C:\\Users\\User\\L2_ScriptsPro\\18_Project_JavaScript\\JS01_Converter_Excel_Json\\data_converter.xlsx"); 


    let f_excelSheet = f_excelWB.SheetNames;

    //console.log(file_excelSheet);
    
    let f_dataJson = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(f_excelWB.Sheets[f_excelSheet[0]]); 

    console.log(f_dataJson);

   // Intent of create the json file.

    let f_dataExport = XLSX.writeFile(f_dataJson, 'data_v1.json');


    console.log("SuccesFileConverter");

};

converterExcelToJson();
```

Error que se muestra

```
C:\Users\User\L2_ScriptsPro\18_Project_JavaScript\JS01_Converter_Excel_Json\node_modules\xlsx\xlsx.js:15017
        if(!wb || !wb.SheetNames || !wb.Sheets) throw new Error("Invalid Workbook");
                                                ^

Error: Invalid Workbook
    at check_wb (C:\Users\User\L2_ScriptsPro\18_Project_JavaScript\JS01_Converter_Excel_Json\node_modules\xlsx\xlsx.js:15017:48)
    at writeSync (C:\Users\User\L2_ScriptsPro\18_Project_JavaScript\JS01_Converter_Excel_Json\node_modules\xlsx\xlsx.js:21135:2)
    at Object.writeFileSync (C:\Users\User\L2_ScriptsPro\18_Project_JavaScript\JS01_Converter_Excel_Json\node_modules\xlsx\xlsx.js:21188:9)
    at converterExcelToJson (C:\Users\User\L2_ScriptsPro\18_Project_JavaScript\JS01_Converter_Excel_Json\index.js:20:29)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\L2_ScriptsPro\18_Project_JavaScript\JS01_Converter_Excel_Json\index.js:27:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estimad@s compañeros, como pueden apreciar, he intentado exportar un archivo en formato .json, sin embargo no logro encontrar una solucion para este inconveniente, estuve leyendo un poco la documentacion de "SheetsJS" https://sheetjs.com/, sin embargo no la comprendo a cabalidad que paso se deberia seguir para que luego de lograr convertir la informacion de una tabla de Excel a formato Json, se guardo en un archivo del mismo tipo Json, para ser utilizado posteriormente.

Su gentil ayuda, con el siguiente paso o implementación que le falta a este código para lograr dicho cometido.

Agradezco como siempre de antemano su amable atención y disposición para solucionarlo.